# Anomaly detection with PCA in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib, pca, anomaly-detection

### I read the following article

### [Anomaly detection with Principal Component Analysis (PCA)](https://help.sap.com/viewer/6a2cd93857fd4973baa558931701afcd/1.0.4/en-US/bd98a950503e4277ae9acb3274ddc9a4.html)

In the article is written following:

•   PCA algorithm basically transforms data readings from an existing coordinate system into a new coordinate system.

•   The closer data readings are to the center of the new coordinate system, the closer these readings are to an optimum value.

•   The anomaly score is calculated using the Mahalanobis distance between a reading and the mean of all readings, which is the center of the transformed coordinate system.

Can anyone describe me more in detail about anomaly detection using PCA (using PCA scores and Mahalanobis distance)? I'm confused because the definition of PCA is: PCA is a statistical procedure that uses an orthogonal transformation to convert a set of observations of possibly correlated variables into a set of values of linearly uncorrelated variables“. How to use  Mahalanobis distance when there is no more correlation between the variables?

Can anybody explain me how to do this in Spark? Does the pca.transform function returns the score where i should calculate the Mahalanobis distance for every reading to the center?

Comment: Please provide info about language. Is scala ok?

Comment: If possible, i'd like the Java language. Otherwise, it can be scala.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets assume you have a dataset of 3-dimensional points.
Each point has coordinates `(x, y, z)`.
Those `(x, y, z)` are dimensions.
Point represented by three values e. g. `(8, 7, 4)`. It called input vector.

When you applying PCA algorithm you basically transform your input vector to new vector. It can be represented as function that turns `(x, y, z) => (v, w).`

Example: `(8, 7, 4) => (-4, 13)`

Now you received a vector, shorter one (you reduced an nr. of dimension), but your point still has coordinates, namely `(v, w)`. This means that you can compute the distance between two points using Mahalanobis measure. Points that have a long distance from a mean coordinate are in fact anomalies.

Example solution:

```
import breeze.linalg.{DenseVector, inv}
import org.apache.spark.ml.Pipeline
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.{PCA, StandardScaler, VectorAssembler}
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.{Matrix, Vector}
import org.apache.spark.ml.stat.Correlation
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, Row, SparkSession}
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

object SparkApp extends App {
  val session = SparkSession.builder()
    .appName("spark-app").master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
  session.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")
  import session.implicits._

  val df = Seq(
    (1, 4, 0),
    (3, 4, 0),
    (1, 3, 0),
    (3, 3, 0),
    (67, 37, 0) //outlier
  ).toDF("x", "y", "z")
  val vectorAssembler = new VectorAssembler().setInputCols(Array("x", "y", "z")).setOutputCol("vector")
  val standardScalar = new StandardScaler().setInputCol("vector").setOutputCol("normalized-vector").setWithMean(true)
    .setWithStd(true)

  val pca = new PCA().setInputCol("normalized-vector").setOutputCol("pca-features").setK(2)

  val pipeline = new Pipeline().setStages(
    Array(vectorAssembler, standardScalar, pca)
  )

  val pcaDF = pipeline.fit(df).transform(df)

  def withMahalanobois(df: DataFrame, inputCol: String): DataFrame = {
    val Row(coeff1: Matrix) = Correlation.corr(df, inputCol).head

    val invCovariance = inv(new breeze.linalg.DenseMatrix(2, 2, coeff1.toArray))

    val mahalanobois = udf[Double, Vector] { v =>
      val vB = DenseVector(v.toArray)
      vB.t * invCovariance * vB
    }

    df.withColumn("mahalanobois", mahalanobois(df(inputCol)))
  }

  val withMahalanobois: DataFrame = withMahalanobois(pcaDF, "pca-features")

  session.close()
}
```

Comment: Let assume that i have a 10x3 dataset (10 input vectors of 3 dimensions). After pca (if I use 2 principal components) i should become a 10x2 dataset. This 10x2 dataset is my „my new dataset“ with 2 dimensions. Now i want to explore if the first input vector (the first row of the 10x2) is an outlire. I should now calculate the Mahalanobis distance of this vector(1x2) to the center of the 10x2 dataset?

Comment: Mahalanobis distance uses the covariance matrix and mean values. Now i should calculate the mean of every column (in this case two columns), and the covariance matrix of the dataset 10x2. And than using the Mahalanobis equation i should calculate the distance of the input vector (1x2) to the center.

Comment: But when I calculate a covariance matrix of the 10x2 dataset i become on the main diagonal of the matrix 1.0, and the rest are very small numbers, approximately 0. In my mind, that was expected because the PCA transforms the dataset into uncorrelated variables. Why Mahalanobis distance than?

Comment: This is equivalent to the calculation of Euclidean distance, because covariance matrix identitiy matrix. Am i wrong?

Comment: first comment: yes, that is correct.
I think Mahalanobis distance reasonably well explained here:
http://www.jennessent.com/arcview/mahalanobis_description.htm

Comment: Thank you, it is a very good explanation of Mahalanobis distance. Can you please tell me how to calculate the (10x2) dataset in spark java (the projection of the original dataset to the principal components). I think that pca.transform doesn't returns that.

Comment: @eni provided the solution. If solution satisfies your need consider accepting the answer

Comment: @eni convert to breeze matrix and then call  `inv()` function of breeze (You can look at the second line of `withMahalanobois` function)

Comment: @eni DenseMatrix in breeze uses Scala Array, not Java Array, that why you get compilation Error. Breeze have method called `t`. Just like in udf in my solution (line 5 of `withMahalanobois` function). If you find this helped you solve your problem consider accepting response

Comment: i accept your answe, but I am still confused about using Mahalanobis distance instead of Euclidian. When you calculate the covariance matrix, you got (approximately) a identitiy matrix. Using Mahalanobis distance should be equal to Euclidian than.

Comment: HI, Do I need a train and test set for such outlier detection? If I have a train and test data, how should i use the PCA components derived from the train and use it on the test data and ultimately detect outliers?