# How to project PCA features from train data to test data in spark scala?

Tags: scala, pca, anomaly-detection

I read this link that explains: [Anomaly detection with PCA in Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49530351/anomaly-detection-with-pca-in-spark)

But whats the code to extract PCA features and project them from training data to test data?
From what I understood, we have to use the same set of features for train on test data.